# Handling jQuery $.ajax response data

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, oauth, get

I'm requesting an OAuth request_token with a `jQuery $.ajax`. I get the token as an HTTP response:

`oauth_token=TX5AybIM&oauth_token_secret=g6WMacNyJy0AkJYEtCP1VOjdZB9e9ksh&oauth_callback_confirmed=true`

Error messages on console:

`ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side` and

`SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`

I wish to be able to handle the response for my OAauth authorizing.

```
        //Request Access Token
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:5000/oauth/request_token",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            jsonp: false,
            cache: true,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: params_get,
            processData: false,
            cache : true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                alert(data);
            },
            abort: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("abort"); 
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error");
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/vZGZt/
What's the value of _params_get_?

Comment: params_get is the oauth signature

Comment: Still works fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/vZGZt/1/

Comment: Could it be a browser issue or something do with the back end?

Comment: Can i have a look at the whole source code? I don't think that it's a browser problem. I've tested it with IE9, IE10, FF and Chrome.

Comment: Try adding the "accepts" property to the $.ajax call and then specify text or "text html".  Something may be getting parsed incorrectly and the '=' would give you the invalid left hand assignment if it was somehow getting processed or the '&' got escaped or something of the sort.

Comment: @thevangelist Did you fix this issue? Even I am getting the same error. Its printing the success message, but not able to print the response. :(